# concatenate multiple files with sysdate using PL/SQL and UNIX

Tags: unix, plsql, rename

Good day everyone,

I have the following scenario where I copy multiple files to a different location:

```
osutil.runoscmd('cp /public/basket-upload/B*.csv /logdata/log/');
```

This works perfectly and copies all files beginning with B* to that location.

the next thing I'd like to do is to concatenate the current sysdate to all those files using the following code:

```
osutil.runoscmd('mv /logdata/log/B*.csv /logdata/log/B*'||to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')||'.csv');
```

This doesn't work. Is there a possible way of allowing this rename to happen?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your system for a `rename` command, and read the documentation (there are a few flavours of it). Otherwise, you'll have to do something like this:

```
osutil.runoscmd('cd /public/basket-upload/ && for f in B*.csv; do mv "$f" "/logdata/log/$f'||to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')||'.csv"; done');
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, I have tried your code above, but upon running it, PL/SQL asks me "Enter value for for: " with a textbox to enter a value. I will try to use the rename function in the meantime

Comment: If you mean PL/SQL _Developer_ from Allround Automations, and if you are calling the procedure from a SQL window, then in recent versions you can disable substitution variables using the `&` button at the bottom of the window, or else by running it in a Test window.

Comment: That's an sqlplus feature: `&something` is a parameter that you'll get prompted for. In your sql script, add `set define off` -- http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html